# Can a Meteor SimpleSchema be built using by data from the database?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I tried to do the following to define a SimpleSchema object, and then create a Collection2 using it.

```
var y = Schema.find().fetch();  
var s = {};
for (var j = 0; j < y.length; j++){
  s[y[j].name] = {type: String};
  console.log (y[j].name)
} 

Data = new Meteor.Collection("data", { schema: s });
```

I placed this in Meteor.startup(), but it doesn't work... the collection is created, but the schema is empty.  I believe this is because the initial Schema.find() hasn't returned anything on the client - the console.log() line outputs text on the server, but not the client.

So if I need to wait for the data to be sent to the client, isn't it too late to create my Data collection?

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: How Meteor.publish function looks like ? Have you subscribed ? Have you removed AutoPublish package ?

Comment: No, I still have autopublish added.

Comment: `'myObject.schema = new SimpleSchema ({
  "_id": {
    type: String,'`  
etc...